# Is $\mathbf{Z}[X]/(2,X^2+1)$ a field/PID?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification, finite-fields, principal-ideal-domains

I've been asked to determined whether the following are fields, PIDs, UFDs, integral domains:
$$\mathbf{Z}[X],\quad \mathbf{Z}[X]/(X^2+1),\quad \mathbf{Z}[X]/(2,X^2+1)\quad \mathbf{Z}[X]/(2,X^2+X+1)$$

1. The first is a UFD since $\mathbf{Z}$ is, but not a PID since $\mathbf{Z}[X]/(X)\simeq \mathbf{Z}$ is not a field and $X$ is irreducible.
2. The second is a field since $X^2+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbf{Z}$.
3. I am stuck on this one. I don't think it is a field because:
   $$\mathbf{Z}[X]/(2,X^2+1)\simeq \mathbb{F}_2[X]/(X^2+1)$$
   But $X^2+1$ is not irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_2[X]$ since $(X+1)(X+1)=X^2+1$, so it is not a field. But I can't see how to go further.
4. As in 3. this is $\mathbb{F}_2[X]/(X^2+X+1)$, and $X^2+X+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_2$ so it is field.

Are 1, 2, and 4 correct? How can I go further with 3? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your argumentation for the second one does not work, because $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is not a principeal ideal domain. Notice that $(2,X^2+1)$ is a proper ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ which properly contains $(X^2+1)$, so $(X^2+1)$ is not maximal.

Comment: @JendrikStelzner Ah yes, I got confused. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is not a PID because the ideal $(2,X)$ is not principal.
2. $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+1)$ is the ring of Gaussian integers, which is a PID. It is not a field, because $2$ is not invertible (for instance).
3. $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(2,X^2+1)$ is not even a domain, because as you noticed $X^2+1=(X+1)^2$ in $\mathbb{F}_2$.
4. Your answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just a bit confused about 3.: why does $X^2+1=(X+1)^2$ not make it a UFD? A bit new to all this.

Comment: The "D" in UFD stands for domain. So if a ring isn't a domain, it can't be a UFD. And $\mathbb{F}_2[X]/(X^2+1)$ isn't a domain because the image of $X+1$ is non-zero but its square is zero.

Comment: Argh so sorry, I was thinking in $\mathbb{F}_2[X]$ and not the quotient ring... Silly. Sorry, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $(X+1)^2 = X^2+2X+1= X^2+1+2X$, so the class of $(X+1)^2$ in $Z[X]/(2,X^2+1)$ is zero and thus the class of $X+1$ is a divisor of zero.